# How do I answer questions about my long term goals in PhD interviews?

Tags: interview

So I'm planning to answer with a mixture of apply for postdoc or go to work in a industry in this field

some answers have recommended to answer what will we get out of you with amongst other things, publications - is this not too cocky to answer with publications?

Also is it to cocky to say I am hoping it will open up new lines of inquiry? or not?

thanks

Comment: They want to hear that you are going to pursue a career in research.  Assure them that you want to do research for the rest of eternity and they will be satisfied.

Comment: What are the downvotes for? I did not upvoted because IMHO, the question is not particularly well-phrased or well-formatted. However, it appears to be fully on-topic, relevant, and objectively answerable, in about the same way as questions about typical interview questions for industry positions are acceptable on [workplace.se].

Comment: I am thinking that the downvoting is people are interpretting the question as to be asking how to game the system or otherwise be dishonest, answering in a contrived way rather than actually saying what your personal long term goals are, why you want a PhD, and what you believe you have to contribute. I think Pete's answer makes it clear that this is actually quite a useful question, as lots of people wonder how best to "say the right thing" at least partly due to culture (this being so typical in job interviews), which is counter-productive for everyone involved.

Comment: I imagine the downvotes are because the question is lacking proper grammar and is quite hard to read.

Answer (score 8):

It sounds like you are trying to game the system by figuring out in advance what answer the interviewers want to hear.  From the perspective of someone who was first a student, then a faculty member and is now the coordinator of my department's PhD program, I have to say that I think there's a real risk that you'd be "gaming yourself": spending 4-7 years in a program with true motivations different from those that the parties that admitted you think you have risks making *the entire experience* a waste of your time.

I actually think that you would be "shooting yourself in the foot less" if you just gave an honest, off-the-cuff answer.  However, better yet is to take the fact that you're thinking about this in advance as an opportunity: indeed, what are your motivations for pursuing a PhD program?  Are they a little fuzzy?  Do you have concerns that your motivations are not well aligned with what the faculty involved in the PhD program would want? Work through that and ask about it.

Comment: +1. Honesty is the best policy, both with yourself and with the interviewers.

Comment: "It sounds like you are trying to game the system by figuring out in advance what answer the interviewers want to hear." - although I consider it likely that this effect is weaker for the average academic position compared to the average industry job interview, that is pretty much how job interviews work.

Comment: You have to game the system now.  Everyone else is going to.

Comment: @O.R. Mapper: I am the graduate coordinator of my department and am currently making last-minute preparations for our visitation day, which takes place tomorrow.  So I speak from experience when I say that I want students to be honest about their motivations and knowledge.  If I asked a student what their long term goal in getting was in getting a PhD, if they didn't know then that's the answer I would like to hear, and it would not be held against them.  If I felt a student was trying to bs me, that would be a potential red flag.

Comment: @Hobbes: That is really not the case for math PhDs at American universities, at least.  I can assure you that the average applicant, successful or otherwise, is quite professionally naive.  Maybe it is otherwise elsewhere, and if so it would be very helpful if you could provide specific information.  An anonymous "No it isn't" is not helpful.

Comment: @PeteLClark: "if they didn't know then that's the answer I would like to hear, and it would not be held against them." - I see no reason to doubt *you* would act like that. I may even believe that could be somewhat representative of academia as a whole. Still, I'd argue that in general, there is a widespread perception that competitive interviews are in part more about knowing the *right* answers than the *truthful* answers.

Comment: I think that giving an honest answer to the "long term goal" question is the only way to go. Still in my PhD, I can already read new students. "I want to research forever. Academia sounds cool" is bs they think they should be saying. "Well, what I want to do is simulate things like _____, so I am interested right now in learning ___ and ___, and maybe doing some ____ to get to ___ ...", it's obvious that person is wants a PhD for the right reasons, and you can't drip with that kind of enthusiasm unless you mean it (or you're a really good actor who studied hard, or lying to yourself).

Comment: Honesty is great, 100% agree.  I wouldn't trust the other applicants to be 100% honest though.

Comment: @Hobbes: I know very well that students (and faculty, and staff, and administrators, and people in general) are a lot less than 100% honest.  You seem to be assuming at least three things: (i) that the single goal of a PhD interview is to get the PhD offer, (ii) that the answer to this question is a crucial factor in the admissions decision and (iii) there is a fixed set of answers that faculty interviewers want to hear from everyone.  In my own direct experience as Graduate Coordinator, none of these are true.  In their absence, there need not be a reward for dishonesty in any sense.